# Rabbitmq quorum queue add follower

Tags: rabbitmq

Initially, we built 2 clusters (nodeA, nodeB) with rabbitmq and created quorum in the cluster.
However, knowing that two nodes cannot mirror, I added one node (node C) as a cluster during Rabbitmq operation, but the new node is not added to followers in the existing quorum queue. Is it possible to manually add a new node to followers?

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible. See the documentation [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html#replica-management)

the command you are looking for is:

```
rabbitmq-queues add_member [-p <vhost>] <queue-name> <node>
```